# The articles before a set on nouns?

Tags: articles

**article + noun + conjunction + [article 2] + noun 2**

Should we use [article 2] and in what situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If article 2 and article one are the same, then don't repeat it.

Example 1: The dog and cat are friends.

Not: The dog and the cat are friends.

Example 2: The dog and a cat are friends.
Basically, it is a known thing and an unknown.

Another example of when to use both:
Did you have the leftover soup for dinner?
Yes, I had the soup and a salad.

Comment: Do adjectives change something?

Comment: "The black dog and white cat are friends?" is correct?  And "The black dog and the white cat are friends?" - is not?

Comment: They are both equal in meaning and both are correct. As a native speaker I would drop the second article but either is correct and understandable.